# Angular Session var not updating

Tags: angularjs

I have been implementing a login feature in my Angular app and have it working for the most part. I am trying to show the userName in the header section. But it won't update after they login until the refresh the screen. What do I need to add to refresh that data?

I am including my header bar like so:

```
<div data-ng-include="'app/layout/topnav.html'"></div>
```

Here is my top nav section that I need the two way binding for Session.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.layout')
        .controller('TopNav', TopNav);

    TopNav.$inject = ['$route', 'routehelper', 'Session', 'authentication'];

    function TopNav($route, routehelper, Session, authentication) {
        /*jshint validthis: true */
        var vm = this;
        var routes = routehelper.getRoutes();
        vm.isCurrent = isCurrent;
        vm.userName = Session.userName;

        activate();

        function activate() { getNavRoutes(); }

        function getNavRoutes() {
            vm.navRoutes = routes.filter(function(r) {
                return r.settings && r.settings.nav;
            }).sort(function(r1, r2) {
                return r1.settings.nav - r2.settings.nav;
            });
        }

        function isCurrent(route) {
            if (!route.title || !$route.current || !$route.current.title) {
                return '';
            }
            var menuName = route.title;
            return $route.current.title.substr(0, menuName.length) === menuName ? 'current' : '';
        }

        vm.logout = function() {
            vm.userName = null;
            authentication.logout();
        };
    }
})();
```

Here is my Session Service:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('blocks.authentication').service('Session', function() {
        this.create = function(userId, userName, userRole) {
            this.userId = userId;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.userRole = userRole;
        };
        this.destroy = function() {
            this.userId = null;
            this.userName = null;
            this.userRole = null;
        };
        return this;
    });
})();
```

Including the nav like this, it only runs once. So once the Session is actually set on my log in page, it does not update here. Am I missing something? What is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I would rather suggest you to rewrite this using a Service which does manage authentication and session by removing the unnecessary code fragments from the controller. Controller should have minimum number of lines which should apply directly to its own scope - ex. data manipulation actions. Everything else should be inside services and directives. If you need further insights pls update, can provide a sample.

Comment: So I have the Session in a service, but how do I output this without assigning it in my Controller?

Comment: You have to inject the Session details to the active controller and assign the details to a scope variable. Then you can use that assigned variable to display the details inside HTML.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I did?

Comment: Yes, but in order to keep the best practice, better to use the assignment as given below in my answer.

Comment: What if instead of setting `vm.userName = Session.userName` you change it to `vm.userName = Session.getUserName()`, where `Session.getUserName` is `function() { return userName; }`

Comment: @Tom That did not work either. Same outcome. Trying option 2 in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options, the first should work.

First, instead of setting `vm.userName = Session.userName` you should change it to `vm.userName = Session.getUserName()` where `Session.getUserName` is like:

```
function getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
}
```

This is because when the controller is instantiated it sets `vm.userName` to whatever the value of `Session.userName` is at that point in time.  It never knows about the change.  Setting it to a function, it should check for that during every `$digest` cycle.

Otherwise, you could use a good old fashioned `observer` pattern to solve the issue.

In the `TopNav` controller:

```
 // Register the setting of vm.userName as an observer
 Session.registerObserverCallback(function () {
     vm.userName = Session.userName;
 });
```

And then in `Session`:

```
this.create = function(userId, userName, userRole) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userRole = userRole;

    // Everytime this changes, notify everyone
    this.notifyObservers();
};

// Since almost everything in angular is a singleton, anyone can register here
// and whenever notifyObservers() is called, everyone gets notified of the new values
var observerCallbacks = [];

var registerObserverCallback = function (callback) {
    observerCallbacks.push(callback);
};

var notifyObservers = function () {
    angular.forEach(observerCallbacks, function (callback) {
        callback();
    });
};
```

Comment: The second option does work but makes me wonder if this is the best approach. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is a sample Controller to display the injected Session details. I assumed, the Session object contains the data. Session is the generated service.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('SessionController', function($scope, Session) {
   $scope.userName = Session.userName;
}
```

Sample usage

```
<div>{{userName}}</div>
```

Comment: This is the exact same as what I currently have except I have the VM model compared to the $scope model. Both approaches give the same problem.